# Why is it difficult to use MySQL ENUMs with Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

At [Doctrine and mySQL Enum](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) I read:

> Mysql Enums
>
> The type system of Doctrine 2 consists of flyweights, which means
>   there is only one instance of any given type. Additionally types do
>   not  contain state. Both assumptions make it rather complicated to
>   work with  the Enum Type of MySQL

I would enjoy a layman language explanation about what it means. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The type system of Doctrine 2 consists of flyweights, which means
>   there is only one instance of any given type.

Flyweight classes create immutable value objects. So in this way they're similar to Strings i.e.

```
$String = "myString";
```

This creates a String object, which cannot be changed. Any alterations to this result in a new String object. Flyweight classes are similar in that once a new object is created via the constructor, it cannot be changed, and it holds the same value. However, Flyweight classes are ultimately more expendable than just using Strings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern has some good examples using an example in several languages of a Flyweight class CoffeeFlavour in a larger CoffeeShop implementation. Here's one that should be an example of a PHP one I've quickly mocked up:

```
<?php
class CoffeeFlavour {
  private $name;

  function __construct(String newFlavor) {
    $this->name = newFlavor;
  }

  public __toString() {
    return $this->name;
  }
}
```

So each instance of CoffeeFlavour is its own CoffeeFlavour to be used in orders, etc.

---

> Additionally types do not contain state.

To elaborate on the above: Similar to strings, a Flyweight class cannot have an instance changed. It is what it is once it is constructed. So in the above example, the String "myString" is exactly that. Any alteration in the String would result in a new object being created.

To use the CoffeeFlavour example, it would be quite ridiculous to change the flavour of the coffee! This is why you don't see a setName() method. In other words, see the following:

```
$caffeineCoffee = new CoffeeFlavour("Caffeinated");
$decafCoffee = new CoffeeFlavour("Decaf");
```

There's no way you'd want to say that the "state" of the caffeinated one suddenly changed to decaf. You would instead create a *new* distinct drink. This adds to the immutable nature of them.

When I order my drink, I say: `$myDrink = $caffeineCoffee;` and therefore reference the object of the featherweight class. These objects don't have a state, they just are, what they are.

On the flip side, MySQL has a column (type), of which it has a **state**, based on a list of values. So this directly conflicts with doctrine2's methodology. The below elaborates further.

---

> Both assumptions make it rather complicated to work with  the Enum
>   Type of MySQL

According to MySQL's documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html page:

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

In this case, the MySQL column (type) contains a state (which of the allowed values it holds). These are determined when the table is created, and any change in the allowed values requires a drop and rebuild of the table. However, Flyweight classes (as above) easily have new instances added as required. Each type (instance) of the Flyweight class being unique, and immutable.

So in summary:

- Flyweight classes (like CoffeeFlavour) aren't overwritten, they have additional instances added as needed.
- These instances would never change state. They would always be what they were when they were created.
- Instances of the Flyweight class are several unique objects with no state, as opposed to one MySQL column with several possible states.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Okay glad it helped! If I can clarify anything further, or simplify, let me know. Otherwise, an upvote / answer mark would be great! :)

Comment: "**Additionally** types do not contain state"? Maybe if you explain it  separately from the first part about Flyw., it helps even more.

Comment: Okay, I thought that would have been covered by the string example, but I'll elaborate. It probably could be clearer.

Comment: Good, Nice of you! (I am not native english, but 'addionally' seems to me to be misused, usually doesn't it introduce a further, **different** reason?)

Comment: Thanks! I agree that "additionally" is a bit ambiguous (could mean more than one thing). So I could say: "1 + 1 = 2, additionally 0.5 + 1.5 = 2" or I could say "1 + 1 = 2, additionally 1 + 2 = 3". It could be another way to state the same point, or state a different point. It's similar to saying "as well" at the end of a statement. That's languages for you! ;)